# pass data from one controller to another controller laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

i want to pass $data array data to another controller. if I can pass that data to the next controller I can insert that data into the database. what is the correct way to do this functionality

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function paymentprocess(paymentRequest $request){
        $data=array();
        $data['name']=$request->name;
        $data['phone']=$request->phone;
        $data['email']=$request->email;
        $data['city']=$request->city;
        $data['address']=$request->address;

        if ($request->payment=='esewa') {
            toastr()->success('payment method esewa');
           return view('pages.payment.esewa')->with('cartcontent',Cart::content());
        }
       

    }
    //
}
```

another controller is

```
class EsewaController extends Controller
{
    public function success(Request $request){

        $setting=Setting::first();

        foreach (Cart::content() as $carts) {
            $rowid=$carts->rowId;
            }

        if(isset($request->oid) && isset($request->amt) && isset($request->refId)){


               $refId=$request->refId;
               if($request->session()->has('coupon')){
                $balance =$request->session()->get('coupon')['balance'];
                    $amt=number_format($balance*(1+$setting->vat/100)+$setting->shipping_charge,2);

                 }else{
                     $amt=Cart::subtotal()*(1+$setting->vat/100)+$setting->shipping_charge;
                 }

            $url = "https://uat.esewa.com.np/epay/transrec";

            $data =[

                    'amt'=>$amt,
                    'rid'=>$refId,
                    'pid'=>$rowid,
                    'scd'=> 'EPAYTEST'
                ];


                $curl = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $response = curl_exec($curl);

                curl_close($curl);


                if(strpos($response,'Success')==true){
                    $user_id=Auth::id();
                      Order::create(['user_id'=>$user_id,'amt'=>$request->amt,'oid'=>$request->oid,'refId'=>$request->refId,'status'=>1,'payment_method'=>'esewa']);
                    //  $info=access $data from 1st controller method at  paymentprocess(paymentRequest $request)
                      Shipping::create(['order_id'=>$info->oid,'name'=>$info->name,'phone'=>$info->phone,'email'=>$info->email,'city'=>$info->city,'address'=>$info->address,'payment'=>'esewa']);
                      toastr()->success('payment success and your order has been placed ');
                      return redirect(route('index'));

                }else{
                  toastr()->warning('Transaction failled try again');
                  return view('pages.payment')->with('cartconten',Cart::content());
                }

            }


    }
```

after the succeess response i want to push that data into database in to shipping table

Comment: your can create instance of another controller and user like `$foo = new FooController();`  then `$foo->methodCall()`

Comment: can you help me with code

Comment: those r codes can u see it ?